# Testing my Repository class which needs to mock Microsoft Entity Framework Identity UserManager

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, asp.net-identity-2

I want to unit test my MyUserService which contains my MyUserRepository which accesses the Entity Framework Identity UserManager.

However I'm having trouble mocking the UserManager/UserStore.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21194324/633415) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/dn314429.aspx) as a guide this is what I've come up with so far:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task FindUserByNameAsync_State_Expectation()
{
    var data = new List<User> 
    {
        new User { UserName = "AAA" }, 
    }.AsQueryable();
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<User>>();
    mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<User>>()
        .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
        .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<User>(data.GetEnumerator()));
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>()
        .Setup(m => m.Provider)
        .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<User>(data.Provider));
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
    mockSet.As<IQueryable<User>>()
        .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
        .Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

    //this obviously doesn't work as userStore doesn't 
    //have a Users property only UserManager does
    var mockUserStore = new Mock<UserStore<User>>()
        .Setup(c => c.Users)
        .Returns(mockSet.Object);
    var repository = new MyUserRepository(mockQueryableUserStore);
    var service = new MyUserService(repository);

    var user = await service.FindUserByNameAsync("AAA");

    Assert.AreEqual("AAA", user.UserName);
}
```

MyUserService looks like this:

```
public class MyUserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _repository;
    public MyUserService(IUserRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public async Task<User> FindUserByNameAsync(string name)
    {
        var user = await _repository.FindUserByNameAsync(name);
        return user;
    }
}
```

And MyUserRepository like this:

```
public class MyUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IUserStore<User> _userStore;
    public MyUserRepository(IUserStore<User> userStore)
    {
        _userStore = userStore;
    }
    public async Task<User> FindUserByNameAsync(string name)
    {
        using (var userManager = new UserManager<User>(_userStore))
        {
            return await userManager.FindByNameAsync(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Up to now I haven't been passing in the UserManager (or a wrapper of it) to the MyUserRepository constructor preferring to use the IUserStore interface

**Is my only option to wrap the UserManager in an interface as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21194653/633415) and use that to pass into the MyUserRepository constructor?  It seems to me there should be a cleaner way to do this?**

Comment: The accepted answer from the last link in your post seems to cover it pretty thoroughly. As you mock things at higher and higher levels, you should expect your mocks to need more and more complex constructors.

Comment: I'm not sure that is the case, there is no way that I can see that I can mock IUserStore and pass it into MyUserRepository such that UserManager.Find...() will return anything?

Comment: You don't need to test .net framework functionality. That's like testing if string returns an array of characters; Microsoft already is stringent with their quality control.

Comment: However if you created a wrapper for UserManager and inject it, you'll be able to test to see that calls to it are happening where you expect.